# If 6x = y+z and 4x = y-z, express z in terms of x

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

\begin{align}
6x &= y+z\\
4x &= y-z
\end{align}
How to express $z$ in terms of $x$?

I'm not 100% sure on how to solve in terms of x

Comment: $z = 6x - y$ and $z = y -   4x$.. Can you see a way to eliminate $y$ from both equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract the second equation from the first. So you have 
$6x -4x = (y+z) - (y-z).$

Answer (score 1):

$$6x=y+z~........(1)$$
$$4x=y-z~........(2)$$ Substracting (2) form (1) we have,
$$2x=2z$$
$$\implies z=x$$

Answer (score 1):

While the answers given by [absolute friend](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1348880/234597) and [Ebearr](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1348854/234597) are elegant, their method of substracting the two equations from one another works only because the variable $y$ conveniently drops out upon doing so. This would not have been the case if your first equation would have been, say, $6x = 2y + z$.

Of course, in that case, one could have multiplied the second equation by  $2$ before substracting the equations, but as you might imagine, with the equations becoming more complex, it might get hard to see what steps to take to make a variable cancel after substraction. This is why I'd like to show you another approach, which requires less thinking (but may result in more complicated calculations in some cases):

Take any of the two original equations. Let's choose $6x = y + z$. Solve that equation for $y$, acting as if $x$ and $z$ were known. Then you get $y = 6x - z$. Now you know what $y$ can be written as in terms of $x$ and $z$ alone, so that you can take the remaining equation, $4x = y - z$, and insert the result just obtained everywhere $y$ shows up:
\begin{align}
4x &= y - z \\ &= (6x - z) - z \\&= 6x - 2z
\end{align}
Moving the $6x$ to the left-hand side of the equation, one has $-2x = -2z$, or in other words, $x=z$.